# not able to use grok filter properly to find useful info from my log file to be pushed in elastic search : logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, elk

This is first time i am using grok filter , what i want extract useful keys from my log.I am not able to create grok pattern.

I have access.log file and I use logstash to put log data in elsticsearch.

**Sample log**

```
September 6th 2020, 10:30:37:759 am [f657a07c-8c62-46ee-78a3-e7c2a04328b0] info: authentication successful...
September 6th 2020, 10:30:38:179 am [f657a07c-8c62-46ee-78a3-e7c2a04328b0] info: external apiresponse time: 3 ms
September 6th 2020, 10:30:49:200 am [f657a07c-8c62-46ee-78a3-e7c2a04328b0] info: {"path":"/route1","originalUrl":"/media/auth/route1?id=601&userId=9e2681-a188-4978-94b0-04c1d50ad056","timestamp":1599368449200,"uuid":"f657a07c-8c62-46ee-88a3-e7c3a04328b0","responseCode":"200","responseTime":11455,"externalCalls":[{"type":"apis","status":"success","timeTaken":2167},{"type":"pdf-generate-time","status":"success","timeTaken":5302},{"type":"pdf-upload-s3","status":"success","timeTaken":1146}]}
```

I only want to process {"path": ........}   this oject to elastic search and extract all keys as a field in elastic.

my logstash conf file -

```
{
 grok {
   match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:log-level} \[%{DATA:class}\]:%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the log format is always the same, you can use this pattern: `info: %{GREEDYDATA:text}$`

In your examples, it will create a field named text with this values:

```
authentication successful...
external apiresponse time: 3 ms
{"path":"/route1","originalUrl":"/media/auth/route1?id=601&userId=9e2681-a188-4978-94b0-04c1d50ad056","timestamp":1599368449200,"uuid":"f657a07c-8c62-46ee-88a3-e7c3a04328b0","responseCode":"200","responseTime":11455,"externalCalls":[{"type":"apis","status":"success","timeTaken":2167},{"type":"pdf-generate-time","status":"success","timeTaken":5302},{"type":"pdf-upload-s3","status":"success","timeTaken":1146}]}
```

You can then use the json filter to parse it.